Reference for Schur's lemma for $C^*$-algebras
In page 11 of these notes: https://math.berkeley.edu/~qchu/Notes/208.pdf it is claimed that Schur's lemma for $C^*$-algebras says that the endomorphisms of an irreducible representation of a $C^*$-algebra are multiples of the identity. I'm having trouble finding a reference for this.

It's definitely not standard terminology, so I doubt you'll find a reference for it. The lemma simply says that a representation $\pi$ of $A$ is irreducible if and only if $\pi(A)'=\mathbb C\,I$, where $$\pi(A)'=\{T\in B(H):\ T\pi(a)=\pi(a)T,\ a\in A\}$$ is the commutant of $\pi(A)$. The use of $\operatorname{End}_A(H)$ for the commutant is what is non-standard notation in the C$^*$-algebra world.
The result is not even a lemma depending on how one defines irreducible. It is common to define irreducible precisely as saying that $\pi(A)'=\mathbb C$, or equivalently that $\pi(A)''=B(H_\pi)$. If one defines irreducible as having no non-trivial invariant subspaces, then one needs a little bookkeeping (of the sort in the proof of Lemma 2.35 in Qiaochu's notes) to show the equivalence of "has no non-trivial invariant subspaces" and "$\pi(A)'=\mathbb C$". When a tiny bit of von Neumann algebra theory is available (namely, the Spectral Theorem and the Double Commutant Theorem), the converse can be proven directly as $\pi(A)'$ is a von Neumann algebra and hence generated by its projections.
